# Buttons not working when switch to second activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

*Hi all ,
I am new to android and i have one doubt.
I have two activities in my app.
When i go to second activity using button and press button in second 
activity that button does not work.*

First activity (Main Activity)

```
public class dashBoard extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnEmiCalculatorVar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);

    btnEmiCalculatorVar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEmiCalculator);
    btnEmiCalculatorVar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc_emi);

        }
    });
}
}
```

*Second activity* added just because it was saying MOSTLY CODE.

```
public class calcEmi extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnCalculateVar;
TextView editText4;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc_emi);
    editText4       = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmiResult);
    btnCalculateVar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);


    btnCalculateVar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText4.setText("Button is Clicked");//this part not working
         }
    });

}
}
```

*Main acivity XML file*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.rathod.nitin.emicalc.dashBoard">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnEmiCalculator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="EMI CALCULATOR"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginEnd="110dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnEmiCalculator"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/btnEmiCalculator" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Second activity XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.rathod.nitin.emicalc.calcEmi">

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="EMI CALCULATOR"
     android:textSize="20sp"
     tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
     android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
     tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/txtEmiResult"
     android:layout_width="90dp"
     android:layout_height="24dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
     android:text="Test"
     android:textSize="20sp"
     app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView5"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
     tools:layout_constraintBaseline_creator="1"
     tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />
  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc_emi); is just to set view. Not to go to next activity. **Use intent**

Comment: use `startActivity(new Intent(this, calcEmi.class));` instead of `setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc_emi);`

Comment: You realize that you don't have a button in your 2nd activity?

Answer (score 0):

... Tough one.

First of all, you are not starting your 2nd `Activity`. Your  `setContentView()` call inside button's `onClick()` does nothing but swapping the layout XML files, which is irrelevant in this situation, `Activity` stays the same. Consider using an `Intent` to start your 2nd `Activity`.

Secondly, notice that your 2nd `Activity` has no `Button`, just 2 `TextViews`. You'll get a `ClassCastException` while binding it from XML to your in-code reference since it's a `TextView`, not a `Button`. Not to mention the `NullPointerException` which you'll get from `findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate)`, since it doesn't seem to exist in your XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are trying to replace the view instead of starting the activity. 
inside the onClick function write this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

instead of

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc_emi);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to start your second activity.

Replace:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc_emi);
```

with:

```
startActivity(new Intent(dashBoard.this, calcEmi.class));
```

And you don't have any Button with id `btnCalculate` in your `activity_calc_emi.xml` file. So it will throw a null exception.